# Drizzle ORM issue with count and filtering

Tags: javascript, drizzle

There has to be better way to do this right? There must be a way to have 1 base query and then one returns values other one returns count

This does work, but it requires to duplicate all of the filtering for each query

```
const drizzle = await db();

// Base query for fetching rows with filters applied
let rowsQuery: any = drizzle
  .select()
  .from(verTable)
  .orderBy(verTable.id)
  .limit(limit)
  .offset(offset);

// Base query for counting total rows with same filters
let totalQuery: any = drizzle.select({ value: count() }).from(verTable);

// Apply filters to both queries
if (title) {
  rowsQuery = rowsQuery.where(ilike(verTable.title, `%${title}%`));
  totalQuery = totalQuery.where(ilike(verTable.title, `%${title}%`));
}
if (industryDesc) {
  rowsQuery = rowsQuery.where(
    or(
      ilike(verTable.industry, `%${industryDesc}%`),
      ilike(verTable.desc, `%${industryDesc}%`)
    )
  );
  totalQuery = totalQuery.where(
    or(
      ilike(verTable.industry, `%${industryDesc}%`),
      ilike(verTable.desc, `%${industryDesc}%`)
    )
  );
}
if (state) {
  rowsQuery = rowsQuery.where(ilike(verTable.state, `%${state}%`));
  totalQuery = totalQuery.where(ilike(verTable.state, `%${state}%`));
}
if (company) {
  rowsQuery = rowsQuery.where(ilike(verTable.company_name, `%${company}%`));
  totalQuery = totalQuery.where(
    ilike(verTable.company_name, `%${company}%`)
  );
}

// Execute the queries
const rows = await rowsQuery;
const total = await totalQuery;
```